# How can I stop Apache from decoding my URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that redirects to another.

Here is the contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (optout|optin|greenarrow|gocharge|subscriber)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://example.com/campaign%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/campaign/urlshortener?id=$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

My problem is, when I pass in:

```
http://redirectsite/d7cd5c%7B%7Bpurl%7C6%7D%7D
```

It sends me to:

```
http://example.com/campaign/urlshortener?id=d7cd5c{{purl|6}}
```

I need it to send me to:

```
http://example.com/campaign/urlshortener?id=d7cd5c%7B%7Bpurl%7C6%7D%7D
```

The reason is that Tomcat 9 has a library that no longer accepts certain characters. So I get the following error in its current state:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [`/campaign/urlshortener?id=d7cd5c{{purl|6}}`]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

What do I need to change or add in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: The `B` flag should be able to achieve that, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: I have tried that but it didnt work. Do i need to restart httpd for it to take effect?

Comment: No, but your browser might have cached the redirect already, so try and clear your history, or test in a new private tab/window. (This is the effect of using R=301, which is why for testing purposes you should always use R=302 instead first.)

Comment: @CBroe thanks, that seems to work, I tried in Chrome's incognito mode.

Comment: I had already tried B but it didnt work, then i asked here. I guess my problem was that my browser had cached the redirect not that my htaccess change didnt work.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer please so I can mark it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `B` flag should be able to achieve what you need here.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b:

> The `[B]` flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.